# Regexp not working due to newlines?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

This is what I have so far, trying to convert:

```
[quote="Tom":1m8ud0zc]blah blah[/quote:1m8ud0zc]
```

into

```
<table width="99%"><tr><td class="BBquote"><strong><em>Originally posted by Tom</strong></em><br /><br />blah blah</td></tr></table>
```

But the text between the quote tags can have newlines, which seems to make this not work, can any tell me how to make (.*?) include matching every special char as well?

```
Message = Regex.Replace(Message,
                        @"\[quote=""(.*?)"":.*?](.*?)\[/quote:.*?]",
                        "<table width=\"99%\"><tr><td class=\"BBquote\"><strong><em>Originally posted by $1</strong></em><br /><br />$2</td></tr></table>"
            );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RegexOptions.Singleline`. It changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character instead of every character except \n.

```
Message = Regex.Replace(Message,
                        @"\[quote=""(.*?)"":.*?](.*?)\[/quote:.*?]",
                        "<table width=\"99%\"><tr><td class=\"BBquote\"><strong><em>Originally posted by $1</strong></em><br /><br />$2</td></tr></table>",
RegexOptions.Singleline
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `\n` to express newline. The `.` matches everything except newline